# How to get base URL in Websphere application Server?

Tags: websphere-6.1

I am running my application in WAS6.1. In the same server I have two EAR deployed. One application can be accessed using the URL server.com:port/app1 over http and the other one as server.com:port/app2. In the application1 I am referencing application2 as :

```
<media-access-proxy
        base-url="http://ipaddress:port/app2"
        prefetch-base-url=""
        mode="mode1"/>
```

Since this ipaddress is static so everytime I have to change this if I am moving from dev environment to QA and from QA to production. I want to set it such as that is should take the base url by itself. Does WAS has a properties file like **was.baseurl** which could be placed in place of **ipaddress:port**? Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The schema requires URI so you can't use anything special. However you can use a DNS name which is same for both environments. Use something like http://server:9080/app2 and add server to both servers' hosts file.